# Custom field in core modules

Tags: custom-field

I need to add a new field in modules form screen.

I learn that using this:

/administrator/index.php?option=com_fields&context=com_modules.module

a field can be added.

I was able to create de field but after saving the module the field value is not saved.

What is it that I still need to do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have the solution, man.
I have a plugin to create custom XML for modules, templates, menus and any component.
https://github.com/uzielweb/add_xml_fields

Whith this extension that I create (self congrats), You can add a infinite fields :)

Answer (score 0):

The link works but Joomla 4 has no support for custom fields in modules. Otherwise it would appear in dropdown of com_fields.